# ln complains about no such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, shell, variable-expansion, tilde-expansion

I'm new in shell programming on macosx and have a little problem. I've written the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

function createlink {
source_file=$1

target_file="~/$source_file"

if [[ -f $target_file ]]; then
    rm $target_file
fi

ln $source_file $target_file
}

createlink ".netrc"
```

When I'm executing this script I get the message **ln: ~/.netrc: No such file or directory** and I don't know why this happened! Do you see the error? Thanks!

Comment: If run in your home directory, this script will first `rm` the named file and then fail to link to a file that isn't there. `if [[ $PWD == $HOME ]] ; then echo "error message"; exit 1; fi` should help you avoid that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `tilde expansion` will not happen as the path is in a variable value (`tilde expansion` happens before `variable expansion`). You can ameliorate this issue by using `$HOME` instead of `~`. That is

```
target_file="${HOME}/${source_file}"
```

This should solve your problem.

Further reading: `EXPANSION` section of `man bash`